# SharedPreferences - запретить удаление

Tags: android, защита

При первом запуске, приложение создает определенные SharedPreferences. Вместе с этим, пользователю выдаётся некий бонус. Если удалить данные приложения в настройках самого устройства - приложение будет считать что его только что установили, и выдаст бонусы как для первого посещения. Как можно защититься от этого? Можно ли как-то запретить пользователю удалять их?
И еще такой вопрос - можно ли как-то "узнать" приложению было ли оно установлено ранее, чтобы при установке\удалении\установке - приложение понимало, что пользователь уже устанавливал его и бонус он не получит? )

Comment: А каким образом вы хотите удалить данные приложения?

Comment: В диспетчере приложений - кнопка "удалить данные приложения" или что-то типа того

Answer (score 3):

Может сделать что-то типа бесплатного In App Purchase? А в Google Play проверять, был ли он куплен хоть когда-нибудь. Я бы копал в эту сторону.

Comment: А как бы это взаимодействовало? Т.е. какие классы используются, что передаётся/получается?

Comment: Вот ссылка на документацию: http://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/index.html

Я рекомендую Вам обратить внимание на вариант с Subscriptions. Если я не ошибаюсь, то эта покупка привязывается к аккаунту пользователя. Вот и сделайте при первом запуске проверку, была ли оформлена уже когда-то эта подписка. Если нет, то делайте эту покупку и записывайте в SharedPreferences. В следующий раз, если клиент удалил данные приложения, то опять делайте проверку, но подписка уже будет оформлена.

Comment: В БД маркета ведется полная история что делал юзер, что покупал и проч. В данном случае можно придумать некий продукт (т.н. `consumable`), который будет куплен юзером при запуске приложения за $0 и потреблен (`consumed`) дальше уже отталкиваться от этого. Подробнее [копайте здесь](http://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/v2/api.html) - нужен in-app billing v. >=2

Comment: @Евгений Василенко subscription не канает... Нужен обычный продукт, но который `managed`

Comment: Я правильно понимаю, что приложение уже будет платным и находится в платных категориях?

Comment: Нет, приложение остаётся бесплатным. Платной становится всего одна функция в ней. Для примера приведу Вам игры Angry Birds или Bad Piggies. Вы играете в них бесплатно, но можете купить какие-то улучшения.

Comment: Для IAP минимальная цена — 0.99$. Таким образом, создать IAP item с нулевой ценой не выйдет.

Comment: falstaf, вот как чувствовал ведь... )
есть предложения? Или это только веб-сервис?

Comment: @jimpanzer дал вам хороший совет — отмечайте на своём бэкэнде, получал ли уже этот пользователь бонус или нет. В качестве идентификатора разумно использовать текущий google-аккаунт на устройстве. Иного способа реализовать желаемое вами я не вижу.

Comment: Да, получается что так. Не поможете парой-тройкой ссылок с примерами реализации? Можно ли такое, к примеру, на юкозе замутить? Есть ли бесплатные сервисы?
P.S. не судите нуба строго )

Answer (score 1):

Регистрируйте юзера на своем вебсервисе. При любом запуске - приложение проверяет, зареган ли юзер, если нет - то регает и дает бонус. Других способов обойти то, о чем вы говорите нет.

Comment: А быстро ли с нуля можно поднять? Есть какие-то бесплатные сервисы? Для регистрации достаточно будет не регистрировать юзера "официально", можно просто его устройство запрашивать?